# HTML file in live mode in visual studio code?

Tags: html, django, templates, visual-studio-code

My HTML file is in live mode. I cannot edit it and have to make modifications externally in notepad. Anyone can help me out?

[image]

Comment: how did you get that font lol? maybe just delete that html and create a new one inside vscode maybe it will work now

Comment: I tried again. Reset font settings created a new HTML file but it won't let me edit anything. It keeps running live.

Comment: hmm really strange never seen this before maybe you should check github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: The only way I found past this is to change the extension to "htm" instead of "HTML". Really weird. Never happened to me before.

Comment: hmmm welp now this will help other when they face the same issue